# Proxy + HTTPS = Page doesn't load

Tags: asp.net, iis, https, proxy, web

I've developed a web app, which uses HTTPS and which works fine when I access is it (live). Yet some customers, who use proxy servers, can't access the site. I already tried to use a real certificate (a cheap one and only a trial, but yet valid), but that didn't help.

Everytime one of these users tries to access the site the browser tries to load it until a timeout occurs. One user even was shown an authentication (but I'm not 100% sure if this was due to a proxy, still waiting for response from the customer)

For which reasons can this happen and what can I do about it?

I'm using IIS, ASP.NET (C#) and JS. Sideinfo: The URL contains a port, the internal structure of the network the IIS is running in (not mine) doesn't allow it otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**443** is dedicated port for HTTPS connectivity. Add type 'HTTPS' with default port **443** in Site bindings of hosted site directory. Check after whether SSL is enabled or not? in IE(browser)->Tools->Internet options->Advanced->Security.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTTPS port in your web app's URL isn't port 443, you'll have a problem with corporate proxies that don't like non-standard HTTPS ports.

i.e. I hope your URL looks something like this: http://example.com:443/...